# ¿Es posible buscar un valor tipo Date dentro de un array?

Tags: javascript, underscorejs

Buenas tardes, mi consulta es si tengo un valor tipo `Date` y un array donde sus valores también son tipo `Date`: **¿es posible realizar una búsqueda para ver si hay coincidencias?**.

Estoy haciendo lo siguiente:

```
// time = Sun Dec 13 2015 21:00:00 GMT-0300 (Hora est. Sudamérica Pacífico)

var busqueda = _.findWhere(this.events,{startsAt:moment(time).toDate()});
return !!busqueda;
```

El array contiene:

```
0: Object
$id: 0
$priority: null
endsAt: Sun Dec 13 2015 21:15:00 GMT-0300 (Hora est. Sudamérica Pacífico)
startsAt: Sun Dec 13 2015 21:00:00 GMT-0300 (Hora est. Sudamérica Pacífico)
title: "titulo: 14.12.2015 00:00 - 14.12.2015 00:15"
type: "info"
__proto__: Object
```

Hasta el momento esto solo me devuelve `undefined`.

Comment: Prueba con toDateString();

Comment: dices item.toDatestring() ? . time es tipo moment no Date

Comment: En la segunda parte (justo después de «El array contiene:») ¿no te refieres un objeto en lugar de un arreglo?. Algo como: { llave: 'valor', endsAt: new Date(), startsAt: new Date() }.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Comparar fechas en cualquier lenguaje suele ser una tarea difícil, por todas las variantes que existen y los métodos que cada lenguaje proporcione. En JavaScript una manera efectiva de comparar la igualdad de dos fechas es con el método `getTime`, se puede implementar de manera sencilla un método que verifique si una fecha está contenida en un arreglo:

```
function existeFecha(array, fecha) {
  return array.some(function(f){
    return f.getTime() === fecha.getTime();     
  });
}
```

Con [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/)

```
function existeFecha(array, fecha) {
  return _.some(array, function(f){
    return f.getTime() === fecha.getTime();     
  });
}
```

El método `some` de un array regresa un valor booleano que indica si un elemento cumple la condición especificada en el callback, aquí usamos el método `getTime` para verificar si dos fechas son iguales.

Aquí un demo en [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/seveqikuga/edit?js,console)

Aquí un [post](http://www.enrique7mc.com/2015/12/comparacion-de-fechas-en-javascript/) más detallado

Comment: esto es genial, funciona de maravilla, pero como seria con underscore?

Comment: @LuisRuizFigueroa edite la respuesta con underscore, que es casi idéntica.

Comment: gracias, de que manera puedo hacer que en vez retorne el objecto encontrado ?

Comment: @LuisRuizFigueroa si usas `filter` en lugar de `some`, encontrarás los elementos que cumplen con la condición.

Comment: filter vendría siendo como _.findWhere en underscore?

Comment: @LuisRuizFigueroa `filter` también es parte de underscore, la diferencia es que `findWhere` busca por medio de propiedades de un objeto, pero nosotros estamos haciendo una comparación por medio de métodos, es por eso que re recomiendo usar `filter`

Answer (score 1):

Tomando en cuenta que tenemos un arreglo con 3 objetos `Date` dentro y la variable de la fecha a encontrar:

```
var aEncontrar = new Date('2015/05/05'),
    arreglo = [
        new Date('2015/05/05'),
        new Date('2015/12/24'),
        new Date('2015/09/15')
    ];
```

---

### Uso de librerías

Puedes utilizar una librería como [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) que te brinde herramientas como esas para un filtrado de datos. Ejemplo:

#### Solución 1

> **_.find(list, predicate, [context])**: Ve a través de cada valor en el arreglo, retornando la primer coincidencia que pase la función (predicate), o *undefined* si el valor no pasa el test.

```
var fechaEncontrada = _.find(arreglo, function (fecha) {
    return fecha.getTime() === aEncontrar.getTime();
});
```

#### Solución 2

> **_.some(list, [predicate], [context])**: Devuelve *true* si el valor en la lista pasa el test del predicado (predicate). Se detiene la búsqueda si alguno pasa la prueba.

```
_.some(arreglo, function (fecha) {
    return fecha.getTime() === aEncontrar.getTime();
});
```

---

Existe otra forma parecida pero no brinda el mismo resultado que las anteriores y es con el uso de **jQuery**. Consiste en lo siguiente: brindas un arreglo a iterar y un callback que establece si el valor pasa o no la prueba programada de forma que todos aquellos objetos que coincidan serán devueltos en un arreglo.

> **jQuery.grep( array, function [, invert ] )**: Encuentra los elementos en un arreglo que satisfacen una función de filtro (devuelven *true*). El arreglo original no es afectado.

Documentación en: [jQuery.grep()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/)